# Getting location of all markers in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I started to implement new Android App with Google Maps. And I want to do next things:
1. One user add marker in my application
2. All others users can see this marker in the application.

How I can implement this using standard Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Firebase to store / sync the coordinates of all the markers. The first user will write in the database, and the other users will get the new marker through the `onDataChange()` callback.
You can find more information about it here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start